# Keeping Large Channel Trench Drain Clear

Tags: drain, drainage, gutters, trench

My new garage has a large Channel trench drain in front of it. The architect oversized the trench drain and used a non-typical 12-inch drain. I'm confident that I won't get water in my garage. But on the downside the grate has a very large slots that easily allow leaves to enter. I'm worried about eventual clogging. Aside from replacing the grate (expensive), what are my options. I was thinking about possibly trying to retrofit some wire mesh underneath the existing grates. Or even at the opening of the drain hole at the end. Any other ideas?

[image: Large Channel Trench annel]

Comment: I'd give it a season and see how it goes. You may have to hose it out a couple times a year, but putting a tight mesh up top will just mean the leaves get stuck up there and end up blocking water from flowing in during heavy rains

Comment: Where does it actually drain to?

Comment: @JACK - it drains out the back of my yard with the rest of my down-spots via a 6" leader pipe to a pond near my house. Worried about the 6" pipe eventually getting clogged.

Comment: Do you have screens on your gutters?

Answer (score 3):

If leaves are the only thing getting it it will take years to decades.  Leaves decompose down to aobut 1/50th their volume.  The usually problem with a drain is sand and dirt.

That said:  The grate bolts in.  5 years from now, those bolts may be very hard to remove.  If the grates don't shift unacceptably without the bolts, take them out now, or just leave one in each grade to keep it from sliding sideways.  As an annual measure, remove the bolt, apply a layer of grease, and refasten it.  Garage drains here get a nasty mix of road de-icer and sand.

Comment: Great comment about the grate bolts (pun intended). I was actually thinking about this very thing since I know at the very least I'm going to have to removed the grates for cleaning one or twice a year.  The grates are heavy and fit in the slots. The bolts are pretty unnecessary. Thanks.